# Hosting WCF service in Sitecore 7 application

Tags: wcf, sitecore, sitecore7

I have a WCF service which i am trying to host in Sitecore 7.1 application. The web service with the same configuration works fine when hosting it in a blank Asp.net application. But when trying to run it from Sitecore application, it doesn't work (error below). I have also tried theses solutions but with no luck. I am not sure if they should be working for recent versions of Sitecore.

https://adeneys.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/make-sitecore-host-wcf/
http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/attach_wcf_services_to_sitecore_context/

Edited:

Here are the steps I followed to add the web service to my Sitecore application:

1- I added a web service (.svc) file to my Sitecore project with one web method which returns a test string. I also added AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute to the service class and set the RequirementsMode to AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required.

2- I added the element  to the  element in my web.config. I also added the  element to register my service as an endpoint.

3- I added the svc extension to the “Allowed extensions” parameter of the FilterUrlExtensions processor of the preprocessRequest pipeline.

The error I got when browsing the web service was:

> 404 Not found error

This made me think that Sitecore doesn't recognise svc files. I tried to disable the httprequestbegin pipeline processors to bypass Sitecore request handling, but it was still giving 404.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.  _"it doesn't work"_ is not helpful sadly

Comment: I have edited the question. The error I received was 404 error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you enable http activation for your version of .net and WCF? You can check in programs and features - turn windows features on or off.

Comment: Thanks David. It resolved the issue for me. It is nothing to do with Sitecore. It turned out I don't have the .svc handler mappings installed on IIS by default on Windows 8. Enabling the http activation for WCF from windows features will install those mappings on IIS and allows to process WCF requests. Do you know if it is better to add those handlers to the web.config so they can be deployed on each environment?